# How does this kind of javascript obfuscation work?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I always was curious how this type of obfuscation can be achieved in JavaScript and how it can be decoded (deobfuscated). Below is an example code:

```
var _0x4e9d=["\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65","\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65"];document[_0x4e9d[0x1]](String[_0x4e9d[0x0]](0x3c,0x62,0x75,0x74,0x74,0x6f,0x6e,0x20,0x6f,0x6e,0x63,0x6c,0x69,0x63,0x6b,0x3d,0x27,0x6a,0x61,0x76,0x61,0x73,0x63,0x72,0x69,0x70,0x74,0x3a,0x69,0x66,0x20,0x28,0x64,0x6f,0x63,0x75,0x6d,0x65,0x6e,0x74,0x2e,0x67,0x65,0x74,0x45,0x6c,0x65,0x6d,0x65,0x6e,0x74,0x42,0x79,0x49,0x64,0x28,0x22,0x70,0x61,0x73,0x73,0x22,0x29,0x2e,0x76,0x61,0x6c,0x75,0x65,0x3d,0x3d,0x22,0x6a,0x30,0x30,0x77,0x31,0x6e,0x22,0x29,0x7b,0x61,0x6c,0x65,0x72,0x74,0x28,0x22,0x59,0x6f,0x75,0x20,0x57,0x49,0x4e,0x21,0x22,0x29,0x3b,0x77,0x69,0x6e,0x64,0x6f,0x77,0x2e,0x6c,0x6f,0x63,0x61,0x74,0x69,0x6f,0x6e,0x20,0x2b,0x3d,0x20,0x22,0x3f,0x6c,0x76,0x6c,0x5f,0x70,0x61,0x73,0x73,0x77,0x6f,0x72,0x64,0x3d,0x22,0x2b,0x64,0x6f,0x63,0x75,0x6d,0x65,0x6e,0x74,0x2e,0x67,0x65,0x74,0x45,0x6c,0x65,0x6d,0x65,0x6e,0x74,0x42,0x79,0x49,0x64,0x28,0x22,0x70,0x61,0x73,0x73,0x22,0x29,0x2e,0x76,0x61,0x6c,0x75,0x65,0x7d,0x65,0x6c,0x73,0x65,0x20,0x7b,0x61,0x6c,0x65,0x72,0x74,0x28,0x22,0x57,0x52,0x4f,0x4e,0x47,0x21,0x20,0x54,0x72,0x79,0x20,0x61,0x67,0x61,0x69,0x6e,0x21,0x22,0x29,0x7d,0x27,0x3e,0x43,0x68,0x65,0x63,0x6b,0x20,0x50,0x61,0x73,0x73,0x77,0x6f,0x72,0x64,0x3c,0x2f,0x62,0x75,0x74,0x74,0x6f,0x6e,0x3e));
```

Addendum: Thank you for de-obfuscating it, but I'm only interested in how I can obfuscate my own code like this.

Comment: Be able to read in Hex like Neo?

Comment: [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/pCq5y/)

Comment: Given that so many have been able to read this "obfuscated" code so easily, what would be the point applying it to your own code? Obviously this obfuscation is too obvious.

Comment: well I guess if you can't answer my question you can't tell me there's no point. Unexperienced users obviously can't decode it. Experienced users do not need to steal my code right?
And I'm just curious how it functions and want to know how I can apply it to my code. Debugging javascript would give you the decoded javascript, so no matter what kind of obfuscating you use

Comment: @John Smith (optional), that is not totally correct.  Some JavaScript processors (like the Closure Compiler in Advanced Mode) will do optimizations and code rewrites as well as global variable renamings.  JavaScript compiled by such systems are almost impossible to reverse-engineer, even after passing through a beautifier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually I have now figured out the real way to obfuscate the javascript like that, without having to make each character separately.

http://javascriptobfuscator.com/default.aspx

This is the obfuscator.

Comment: Take any code that is obfuscated by this website, and place it in JSbeautifier. Back to normal! (variable names are changed, peh)

Answer (score 7):

Note that in JavaScript, `someobject["xyz"]` is about the same as `someobject.xyz`.

First statement:

`_0x4e9d` is an array with two strings:

- `"fromCharCode"`
- `"write"`

Second statement decodes to `document.write(String.fromCharCode(0x3c,0x62,...,0x3e))`.

Finally, the string being written is this piece of HTML:

```
<button onclick='javascript:if (document.getElementById("pass").value=="j00w1n"){alert("You WIN!");window.location += "?lvl_password="+document.getElementById("pass").value}else {alert("WRONG! Try again!")}'>Check Password
```

Comment: To decode the string, you basically execute the code line by line as if you were a human JavaScript interpreter. That's the only way to decode stuff in general.

Comment: ok this seems nice and clear explanation. so how can I obfuscate my javascript like this, do I need some software or should I do it all on my own?

Answer (score 4):

Each `\xnn` is a character code as hexadecimal.

So `\x63` will give you an 'a'

To do it to your own code you need to have something that will translate each character to it's hex code point:

```
var aAsHex = '\\x'+'a'.charCodeAt(0).toString(16)
```

Then copy and paste the output to a file.

Comment: that's just the name of the variable. it's named like that so you don't know what it's for.

Comment: I believe that there is a much easier way to do that.

Answer (score 3):

`var _0x4e9d = ["\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x43\x68\x61\x72\x43\x6F\x64\x65", "\x77\x72\x69\x74\x65"];`

is `["fromCharCode", "write"]`

`document[_0x4e9d[0x1]](String[_0x4e9d[0x0]]`

is `document.write(String.fromCharCode`

`String.fromCharCode(0x3c, 0x62, ...)`

Is

```
<button 
  onclick='javascript:if (document.getElementById("pass").value=="j00w1n"){alert("You WIN!");window.location += "?lvl_password="+document.getElementById("pass").value}else {alert("WRONG! Try again!")}'
>
  Check Password
</button>
```

The JavaScript in the `onclick` is

```
if (document.getElementById("pass").value=="j00w1n") {
  alert("You WIN!");
  window.location += "?lvl_password=" + document.getElementById("pass").value
} else {
  alert("WRONG! Try again!")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP, assuming `$string` contains data. So you can obfuscate by running reverse process.

```
echo preg_replace('~((0|\\\)x([0-9a-f]+))~ei', 'chr(hexdec("\\1"))', $string);
```

You will get this...

```
var _�=["fromCharCode","write"];document[_�[]](String[_�[]](<,b,u,t,t,o,n, ,o,n,c,l,i,c,k,=,',j,a,v,a,s,c,r,i,p,t,:,i,f, ,(,d,o,c,u,m,e,n,t,.,g,e,t,E,l,e,m,e,n,t,B,y,I,d,(,",p,a,s,s,",),.,v,a,l,u,e,=,=,",j,0,0,w,1,n,",),{,a,l,e,r,t,(,",Y,o,u, ,W,I,N,!,",),;,w,i,n,d,o,w,.,l,o,c,a,t,i,o,n, ,+,=, ,",?,l,v,l,_,p,a,s,s,w,o,r,d,=,",+,d,o,c,u,m,e,n,t,.,g,e,t,E,l,e,m,e,n,t,B,y,I,d,(,",p,a,s,s,",),.,v,a,l,u,e,},e,l,s,e, ,{,a,l,e,r,t,(,",W,R,O,N,G,!, ,T,r,y, ,a,g,a,i,n,!,",),},',>,C,h,e,c,k, ,P,a,s,s,w,o,r,d,<,/,b,u,t,t,o,n,>));
```

Comment: yeah, yet dont get how to obfuscate my javascript